# Small angle approximation of the integrand of the arc length

Tags: calculus

I am confused by the following approximation made in a book:

The justification made in the book is as follows:

"In the case of a flat curve, the quantity (dy/dx)^2 is small in comparison with unity and, neglecting small quantities of order higher than the second, we obtain approximately"

$\sqrt{1+ \frac{dy}{dx}^2} \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{dy}{dx}^2$

If it's a small angle, how do they get the above approximation? Also, "in the case of a flat curve" does not make any sense.

Comment: Here a "flat" curve does not mean a perfectly straight one, but merely one that is _approximately_ horizontal each point.

Comment: This is called binomial approximation. In general, you can do: $$(1+x)^n = (1 + nx)$$ for x very very less than 1.

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series for $\sqrt{1+t}$ is $\sqrt{1+t} = 1+\dfrac{1}{2}t-\dfrac{1}{8}t^2+\cdots$.

If $t \approx 0$, then we can make the approximation $\sqrt{1+t} \approx 1+\dfrac{1}{2}t$.

In the case of a "flat" curve, $\dfrac{dy}{dx} \approx 0$, and thus, $\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 \approx 0$.

So, substituting $t = \left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 \approx 0$ gives us $\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \approx 1+\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$, as desired.